# What about "inc" (include) files and Child Theming? Is it possible?

Tags: include

What I mean is that I'd like to add "inc" files that are not overwritten when there's an update. Is that even possible?

Comment: You'll need to elaborate. _Anything_ you put inside a parent theme directory will be lost in an update, but inside your own child theme you can put anything wherever you want. There's nothing special about an 'inc' folder.

Comment: So I would simple make sure the path links to my child theme for that particular /inc/ file?

Comment: No, you just place any code you don't want overwritten into the child theme. You don't include child theme files in the parent theme. WP knows by using a child theme that you want it to use the code there first, and if none exists fall back on the parent.

Comment: @henry What path? Please explain what you're trying to do.